# Changing LSCOLORS in WSL2 Ubuntu with oh my zsh doesn't do anything

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh, windows-terminal, ls-colors

I have Ubuntu installed through WSL2 and I also am using zsh as my shell with oh my zsh installed. I am trying to change the default ls colours by adding `export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxBxegedabagacad` in my .zshrc, but it doesn't change any of the default ls colours. I made sure to source the .zshrc file and restarted my terminal as well, but it didn't do anything. In addition, the `export LSCOLORS` line is below this line: `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. Is it possible that oh my zsh is overriding the ls colors that I set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `LS_COLORS` export in your `~.zshrc file` not `oh-my-zsh.sh`. So it would look something like this:

```sh
LS_COLORS="ow=01;36;40" && export LS_COLORS
```

Comment: This party worked, but now when I do the ls command, it gives me this error: "ls: unparsable value for LS_COLORS environment variable". I guess the LS_COLORS value that I used (ExFxBxDxBxegedabagacad) isn't valid (though it works on my laptop). So what's the format for LS_COLORS when using oh-my-zsh?

Comment: Did the values I gave you in the example work? If so this question has been answered. As to the format of LS_COLORS, this is a somewhat involved answer that deserves its own question. However if you want to learn more about exactly what you can change and the proper format to use you can look here http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors

Comment: Yes, the format you gave me worked. I learned that LSCOLORS should be in the format that I used, but I guess it's just different for oh-my-zsh? Either way thanks for giving me that website.